# How to assign different colors to observation points in different clusters using R's clusplot

Tags: r

The R documentation at http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/clusplot.default.html isn't exactly helping me. Code:

```
somedata = read.data("somefile.tsv")
clustered = kmeans(somedata, 5)
library(cluster)
clusplot(somedata, clustered$cluster, cex=0.1, ..??whatshouldgohere??..)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `col.p` argument:

```
clusplot(somedata, clustered$cluster, cex=1, col.p=clustered$cluster)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use col.p argument as David has already said above as:

```
clusplot(somedata, clustered$cluster, cex=1.0, col.p=c ("steelblue", "darkred", "darkgreen"))
```

This will assign different colours to your observation points from the colours specified in the list.

Check this:

```
data(iris)
iris.x <- iris[, 1:4]
cl3 <- pam(iris.x, 3)$clustering
op <- par(mfrow= c(2,2))
clusplot(iris.x, cl3, color = TRUE, cex=0.7, col.p=c ("steelblue", "darkred", "darkgreen"))
```